# nodemcu parse JSOn array

Tags: arrays, json, esp8266, nodemcu

Any idea how I can parse below kind of json array of objects in NodeMCU.

"[{\"PropertyID\": \"9641\",\"DBPollCount\": 0,\"SampleTime\": \"1969-12-31T19:00:00\"},{\"PropertyID\": \"9641\",\"DBPollCount\": 0,\"SampleTime\": \"1969-12-31T19:00:00\"}]";

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the [sjson module](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/sjson/#sjsondecode) (specifically the `sjson.decode()` method)?

```
local jsonString = '[{\"PropertyID\": \"9641\",\"DBPollCount\": 0,\"SampleTime\": \"1969-12-31T19:00:00\"},{\"PropertyID\": \"9641\",\"DBPollCount\": 0,\"SampleTime\": \"1969-12-31T19:00:00\"}]'
local jsonObj = sjson.decode(jsonString)
```

Should do the trick.